# Regex expression meaning for matching 2008-08-30 17:21:59 or 20080830 172159

Tags: regex

I am using following regex for matching Calendar date with hours, minutes, and seconds (e.g., 2008-08-30 17:21:59 or 20080830 172159).

```
^([0-9]{4})(-)?(1[0-2]|0[1-9])(?(2)-)(3[01]|0[1-9]|[12][0-9])●(2[0-3]|[01][0-9])(?(2):)([0-5][0-9])(?(2):)([0-5][0-9])$
```

but i am unable to figure out the meaning of the expression

```
(-)?
(?(2)-)
(?(2):)
```

Comment: It's a quantifier implying 0 or 1 match.  Read a basic tutorial on regex.

Comment: The first one may be a basic feature, the other two are rather advanced :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?` following an item means zero or one of that item. So `(-)?` means either `-` or nothing.

`(?(2)-)` is a conditional expression. It means "if you captured group number 2, match a `-` item here".

Group number two is this one:

```
^([0-9]{4})(-)?...
  11111111  2
            ^
```

So what `(?(2)-)` and `(?(2):)` mean is to match the `-` or `:` character *only* if the original `-` character existed after the year. In other words, either *all* of the separator characters are there or *none* of them are. No chance of passing:

```
20140102 12:34:56
```

as valid since the `:` characters are disallowed due to the `-` missing between `2014` and `01`.